# Odd Session Behavior in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, session-variables

First off, this is my own project, not a homework assignment.

Here's the situation. I have a web application (ASP.NET w/ MVC 5) and I use the session to store certain things (e.g. user info). Now, there are two tabs open, each on one part of the page. We will call them Tab A and Tab B. Here's the scenario:

Tab A is open to Page A

Tab B is open to Page B

In Tab B, the user does an action which requires the update of a session variable. Thus, I write the new data to the session variable via an Ajax call to a controller method.

If I refresh Tab A, however, the data in the session variable does not update for Tab A.

If I then refresh Tab B, then go back to Tab A and refresh, then the data in the session updates for Tab A.

The other odd thing is, if I refresh Tab A, but never refresh Tab B, then Tab B thinks the session data never updated either.

I'm not sure why the session data won't update until I refresh Tab B.

Comment: Set breakpoints on the server. From your description I would not be surprised if the Ajax call is not updating the session the way you think it is.

Comment: I've done this already (I'm not a noob lol). And yes, it is updating the session as it should.

Comment: Have you tried alternate browsers? Maybe it's just a quirk in the particular browser you're using?

Comment: @ChrisPratt has a good point. Try clearing your cookies - maybe they're getting stuck?

Comment: Maybe try taking the AJAX out of the picture to rule out a problem with that?

Comment: It's not the AJAX. Everything updates properly as it should in Tab B and if I never attempt to refresh Tab A, the session data persists. It's only when I refresh Tab A does the session data get messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before - it wasn't the session variable when it happened to me, it was the browser cache. I had to set the page not to cache using a combination of server-side and client-side methods.

Client side I found I needed to do this to force all my supported browsers not to cache:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Server-side I had to do this:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store, must-revalidate");
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0");
```

A little brute force, I'll admit, but this was the only way I could make everything not cache in my environment.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work... not sure what the issue is and apparently no one else has ever encountered this because there is nothing Google can find haha

Comment: I'm not an MVC expert (I work with web forms), but are your tabs in an updatepanel? If you can use an UpdatePanel, maybe put one inside your tab content?

Comment: @Tim: pretty sure OP means "tab" in the sense of a browser tab, not a tab pane type control on the page.